# RestTemplate getForObject with Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I want read String from http response,just like this.
I am trying to do this [see below], and it is throwing error.

1.Client

```
String string=getForObject("http://127.0.0.1:6060/dc-server/rest/dataset/Book/meta", String.class);
```

2.Server

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/dataset/{datasetName}/meta", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDatasetMeta(@PathVariable("datasetName") String datasetName) {
    return service.getDatasetMeta(datasetName);
}
```

spring mvc configure file

```
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"  class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Exception

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@19a6fa1; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@19a6fa1; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.cgs.dc.client.rest.RestConnector.getDatasetMeta(RestConnector.java:55)
    at server/rest/dataset/Book/meta" resulted in 200 (OK)
14:01:05,395 DEBUG RestTemplate:78 - Reading [java.lang.String] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@1371ddd]
```

Response body

```
<dataset xmlns="http://sucsoft.com/DC_DEF" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ......
```

Comment: Using a json message converter isn't good here.'" 'is not a valid char for json. If I still want to use json message, I can use JSONObject.quote("").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service you're accessing is returning an xml response, not a json response. What you probably should do is use JAX-B to convert that xml into a real java object.

With [this eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxb-builder/) you can generate an already annotated java class from your xml document. Then you can use that class in the restTemplate (it doesn't require any special spring xml configuration) as the class you want the xml deserialized into.

Like this:

```
Response response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(null), Response.class);
```

Make sure `Response` is the annotated class.

If you just want a string, then make sure spring isn't trying to deserialize that using a json message converter.

Comment: Thank you very much!I just want a String, I have find the problem.Thanks for your help.